# Win7 Modifying incoming HTTP packet from specific url automatically

Tags: packet, windows-7

Is there an application that can listen in on my PCs http traffic (Preferably process specific), and modify packets that were requested from a certain url ?

So let's say everytime I request http://example.tld/test.html it would replace any occurence of let's say "i" with "I", it's a simple example but still it's an example

Thanks for your time, Xeross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to achieve what you desire using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which describes itself as a "Web Debugging Proxy". I seem to remember that it supports scripting such that you can modify traffic en-route.

Comment: It does what I want, however it can't be minimized to the tray unfortunately.

Comment: Any particular reason you need it to only show in the notification area?